# nginx is sending http call instead https in the host headers to backend iis where azure app is deployed

Tags: asp.net, iis, nginx

i have ngInx in the front-end which is configured with SSL and i am trying to proxy pass to the back-end iis where my azure app is deployed.
while making a request to back end ngInx is passing "http" instead "https" due to which i am not able to authenticate my app, receiving bad request error from azure ad.

So how can i pass "https" in the header while making call to iis back-end azure app instead "http".

I tried looking for the answers in different posts nothing helped till now

Comment: Can you show your nginx confguration for that location?

Comment: server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  domina_name;
        ssl_certificate      .crt";
        ssl_certificate_key  cert.pem.key;
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

Comment: location /dashboard{
                 proxy_pass http://ip:port;
   proxy_set_header HOST $host;
   proxy_buffer_size   128k;
   proxy_buffers   4 256k;
   proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k; }
    }

Comment: @Oliver above one is my nginx config

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in the NginX configuration the the upstream server is SSL.

You should be able to simply use https in the proxy_pass directive, so like `proxy_pass https://ip:port;` , and use `proxy_ssl_verify off;`

More complex configuration is in described here:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-https-upstreams/